# LaTeX editor most like Overleaf

Tags: editors

I really like using Overleaf as a LaTeX editor when I have an internet connection. For times when I do NOT have internet, what local editor (that works in Windows) is most similar in that:

- Adjustable split screen with source code on left, output on right
- Output is periodically updated (can be forced to update) but not constantly instantaneously updated
- Viewer is seamless with the editor, but can be easily printed from
- Simple editor without a lot of extra functionality that I'll never use

For what it's worth, I love TeXworks, but the inability to easily print ruins it.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. I don't have time to go through the huge list in the "similar question" and am asking which is most like Overleaf but runs locally.

Answer (score 1):

[TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) could fit the bill.

- It has split screen in a single window.
- Resulting PDF is refreshed automatically after compilation, but you still have to initiate compilation (which I find highly preferable, given that sometimes when you're typing the code remains in a non-compilable state for quite a while).
- The editor and preview panels are full-featured and linked with synctex.
- It has a lot of features, but it's easy to remove most of them from the GUI and forget about them. That's what I did, because I hate cluttered interfaces and prefer to rely on shortcuts.

Personally I'd use VS Code, but it doesn't really fit the bill for your last point: it's smooth sailing once you beat it into shape, but it takes a while to get there.